# Update the Boolean data type using and and subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

When updating Boolean data types, I can do the following in PostgreSQL:

```
create table demo(id int, ks bool default false);
CREATE TABLE
insert into demo(id, ks) values (1, true);
INSERT 0 1
select * from demo;
  id | ks
 ----+-----
   1 | t 
 (1 row)

update demo set ks=true and id in (select id from demo);
UPDATE 1
```

I get syntax error when I want to do the same with SQL Server.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8 
>  Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'and'.

How can I accomplish the same kind of query in SQL Server?

Comment: There is no such thing as a boolean datatype in sql server. The closest thing is the bit datatype which allows three values (0, 1, NULL). So yes it can be done quite easily. Change the datatype to bit and instead of the string "true" use the bit value 1.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Tb_Table1
(
ID              INT,
BitColumn       BIT DEFAULT 1
)


insert into Tb_Table1 values (1,0)

update Tb_Table1 set BitColumn=false  
and id in ( select id from Tb_Table1 where id=1)


Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

Comment: ???? That update statement makes no sense. Why do you have an AND in your update statement? You should use a WHERE clause. And if you want to use string literals they must be strings because there is no boolean datatype. So you would use set BitColumn = 'false'

Comment: That's the question I'm offering to you. It did not make sense. However, when I run this query, I have updated some data. If it is done in PostgreSQL, then I thought I was doing mssql as well.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server:

```
UPDATE demo
SET ks = 1
```

Because your statement `id in (select id from demo)` means you want top apply this update to all rows.

If you want limit this update to some rows, you'll add a WHERE clause, as follow

```
UPDATE demo
SET ks = 1
WHERE your_condition_is_satisfied
```

Comment: I know I will do what you normally do. I want to be able to do the same in MSSQL as I did in PostgreSQL. 
The above operation is a sample table and I made only one data entry. Can I adapt the query in PostgreSQL to MSSQL?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your simplified example is a bit *too* simplified and is causing some confusion. Perhaps this will illustrate better. Say we have two tables:

```
tbl_parent

parent_id  parent_name  has_partner  single_parent
---------  -----------  -----------  -------------
1          parent1      true 
2          parent2      false
3          parent3      true 
4          parent4      false
```

```
tbl_child

child_id  child_name     parent_id
--------  -------------  ---------
101       parent1child1  1
201       parent2child1  2
202       parent2child2  2
```

If we wanted to populate the `tbl_parent.single_parent column` in PostgreSQL we could just do

```sql
UPDATE tbl_parent 
SET single_parent = (NOT has_partner) AND parent_id IN (SELECT parent_id FROM tbl_child)
```

resulting in

```
parent_id  parent_name  has_partner  single_parent
---------  -----------  -----------  -------------
1          parent1      true         false
2          parent2      false        true
3          parent3      true         false
4          parent4      false        false
```

SQL Server apparently does not support subqueries in the SET expression. However, we can put a subquery in the FROM clause of our T-SQL UPDATE statement, like so:

```sql
UPDATE tbl_parent 
SET single_parent = (~ has_partner) & (child_check.has_children)
FROM 
    tbl_parent 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            tbl_parent.parent_id, 
            IIF(tbl_child.parent_id IS NULL, CONVERT(BIT, 'FALSE'), CONVERT(BIT, 'TRUE')) AS has_children
        FROM 
            tbl_parent
            LEFT JOIN
            tbl_child
                ON tbl_parent.parent_id = tbl_child.parent_id
    ) child_check 
        ON tbl_parent.parent_id = child_check.parent_id;
```